# Haskell: expected type [Char] actual type [[Char]]

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do a checker function but i'm getting an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
Expected type: [Char]
  Actual type: [[Char]]
In the first argument of `isHorizontal', namely `str'
In the expression: isHorizontal str number
```

This is the function triggering it:

```
upCheck :: [[Char]] -> Int -> [Int] -> Bool
upCheck tableArr number posArr = do
    let arv = findVertIndex (tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)) number
    let str = tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)
    if ((posArr !! 0) == 1)
      then False
      else if isHorizontal str number
        then False
        else if (tableArr !! ((posArr !! 0)-1)) !! arv /= 'x'
          then False
          else True
```

Where `tableArr` is an array which contains strings: `["2323","3232","3231","3232"]` and `posArr` is an array which contains correct positions, for example `[1,3]`. `number` is the number we're checking, let's say it's `1`.

Now the `isHorizontal` function is this which tells me basically whether there are two elements in the same row.

```
isHorizontal :: [Char] -> Int -> Bool
isHorizontal [] _ = False
isHorizontal [x] _ = False
isHorizontal (x:y:xs) number =
   if (firstCheck x && firstCheck y)
   then (if digitToInt(x) == number && digitToInt(y) == number then  True else isHorizontal xs number)else isHorizontal (y:xs) number
```

However function isHorizontal works on input "55x32" 5 for example, so the problem is in my upCheck function. And by the looks of it the code: `tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)` should give a string back aswell, so this should fit for isHorizontal function, however it won't..

What am I missing?

Edit:

After adding type to functions the error changed to:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `Char'
Expected type: [[[Char]]]
  Actual type: [[Char]]
In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `tableArr'
In the first argument of `findVertIndex', namely
  `(tableArr !! (posArr !! 0))'
```

Comment: Please always add type signatures to your functions. Not only does this make it much easier for us to understand what you're trying to do, it will also guide yourself while defining the functions.

Comment: Hey @leftaroundabout , I added type signatures, i think they're correct (i'm fairly beginner in haskell) and i tried out in ghci with :t to get the signatures.

Comment: The signatures look reasonable, but I don't think you'd still get the same error message (it's probably a more useful one now!).

Comment: god rid of my answer. misread `let str = tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)` to be accessing with two indexes, sorry

Comment: I also added a new error message in the end if you didn't notice at first, could you take a look on that ?

Comment: I think i found the mistake right now, i'm trying to fix it and post back my results.

Comment: I need the definition of `findVertexIndex` then, since I guess this is ill-defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to define pure functions here. (And that's great, pure functions give you [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency): very nice for reasoning about how you programs will behave!)

However, `do` notation is procedural. You need that for when you're doing *impure* stuff<sup>†</sup> (for instance if you had the signature `[[Char]] -> Int -> [Int] -> IO Bool`, it would mean your “function” were also allowed to do impure sequential IO operations). But you don't need that when writing a simple pure function.

So instead of

```
upCheck tableArr number posArr = do
    let arv = findVertIndex (tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)) number
    let str = tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)
    if ((posArr !! 0) == 1)
      then False
      else if isHorizontal str number
        then False
        else if (tableArr !! ((posArr !! 0)-1)) !! arv /= 'x'
          then False
          else True
```

you probably want

```
upCheck tableArr number posArr
  = let arv = findVertIndex (tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)) number
        str = tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)
    in if ((posArr !! 0) == 1)
        then False
        else if isHorizontal str number
              then False
              else if (tableArr !! ((posArr !! 0)-1)) !! arv /= 'x'
                    then False
                    else True
```

This looks similar, but actually does something quite different: instead of hard-baking a sequence of steps to be taken with `do` (which only works in a monad like `IO`), you merely tell the compiler some definitions, but leave it free to figure out the best order in which to evaluate these.

Indeed, it's customary to write out definitions more in a style like

```
upCheck tableArr number posArr
     = if ((posArr !! 0) == 1)
        then False
        else if isHorizontal str number
              then False
              else if (tableArr !! ((posArr !! 0)-1)) !! arv /= 'x'
                    then False
                    else True
  where arv = findVertIndex (tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)) number
        str = tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)
```

Which is in fact exactly the same as the code with `let...in`.

Note that chains of `if` staments can be written much nicer as *guards*:

```
upCheck tableArr number posArr
     | posArr!!0 == 1                                = False
     | isHorizontal str number                       = False
     | tableArr !! ((posArr !! 0)-1)) !! arv /= 'x'  = False
     | otherwise                                     = True
  where arv = findVertIndex (tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)) number
        str = tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)
```

...though actually, you don't need conditionals at all when writing *boolean* functions. The whole beast is equivalent to simply

```
upCheck tableArr number posArr
    = not (   posArr!!0 == 1
           || isHorizontal str number
           || tableArr !! ((posArr !! 0)-1)) !! arv /= 'x'
          )
  where arv = findVertIndex (tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)) number
        str = tableArr !! (posArr !! 0)
```

This is possible in most programming languages, not just in Haskell.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually, `do` in itself is not impure at all. It uses *monads*, which just happen to allow (amongst other thing) to embed impure code into pure Haskell (in a marvelously safe manner). But you probably want to learn about that later.</sub>

Comment: The problem was actually in findVerticalIndex function which took in [Char] but had to take in [[Char]], after doing a bit reprogramming i managed to reconfigure my things. Thanks for pointing out the usefulness of signatures, i'll mark you as an answer for your help :)

Comment: So basically let-in works in a manner that whatever is in "let" will be variable definitions and whatever is in `in` is for "calculations"?

Comment: @Banana: `f = let x = a in y` (or `f = y where x=a`)  works in fact like what would you would write, in an imperative language, as `f () { x = a; return y; }`, except the order in which you write it doesn't matter.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to have a chat with me and answer some follow up questions i have?

Comment: @Banana: rather not, it's not like I don't have other stuff to do... but I've already written a couple of suggestions now. And if you're serious about learning Haskell, do read a book ([LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) is great).

Comment: @Banana: Remark: If `posArr !! 0` is always used, use `Int` instead of `[Int]`.

Comment: @Zeta: right of course, indeed use of indices is generally a code smell in Haskell.

Comment: Strange fact I only learned recently: `do` (in GHC, at least) does not itself impose a monadic context--that only shows up if the desugaring actually inserts a `>>=` or `>>` or the user inserts something monadic.

Comment: @dfeuer: interesting. I thought this was only the case when using `RebindableSyntax`... but apparently that extension doesn't actually change the way the compiler handles `do`, only how it resolves the names of `>>=` and `>>`.

Comment: @dfeuer: this lends itself to some weird code: `let silly = do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do ()`